# Can I add an external swagger api document in Enterprise Integrator 6.6.0 WSO2?

Tags: swagger-2.0, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I can't find anything about adding an external swagger document in order to expose my API as I want in my EI 6.6.0 WSO2.
Is that possible? How can I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I have tried the solution that I found in the WSO2 EI 7.0.0 but in the 6.6.0 work fine too.

```
<api context="/prices" name="PricesAPI" publishSwagger="conf:prices/swagger/prices_v1_swagger.yaml" version="1.0.0" version-type="context" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
```

I add this property into the api tag and I add the document path in my registry

**publishSwagger="conf:prices/swagger/prices_v1_swagger.yaml"**

I hope to help you